# Concatenate arbitrary number of templates in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I'd like to use `template()` to concatenate some files.  I read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/592728/puppet-concatenate-templates), which is fine if you know exactly how many files you want to concat.  What if I just have an array of input file names?

```
$files = ['mymod/a.erb', 'mymod/b.erb', 'mymod/c.erb']

file { "/var/foo/final":
  content => template ($files)  # <-- error, can't convert Array to String
}
```

I'd like to avoid having to write a parser function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment. There was a [Puppet issue](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/8492) submitted for it and [a fix proposed](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/5158#note-14) but does not seem like there's any rush to implement it.

As a possible workaround, you could have one template include others:

```
<% @template_array.each do |val| -%>
<% scope.function_template(val) %>
<% end -%>
```

Forewarning, I have not tested this but I believe it should work.

Comment: I will try it out and report back.  I was going to ask if it's possible to "call" the puppet `template()` function from inside Proper Ruby.  If so, you could actually skip the extra file and go straight for `inline_template('@arr.reduce ("") { |str, f| str + scope.function_template(f) }')`

Comment: Oh, good idea. I tend to go with separating logic and presentation so I avoid `inline_template` but this is a use case that may be appropriate.

Comment: If your manifest does this a lot (e.g. in a `defined type` that is instantiated in large numbers), this will cause a measurable performance hit. Apart from some boiler plate, a custom function will really not be that much more code, but saves CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @FelixFrank, I will keep it in mind.  It's for a monitoring module, so I can keep "things to monitor" in partial config files and assign those on a per-host basis.  The module should be instantiated once per host, so I think a performance hit should be acceptable.